# ASP.NET with SQL DB sample project to download

Tags: asp.net

In order to test an analytics tool, I need to come up with a .NET web app, one that preferably uses a DB instance, and deploy it. I have SQL Server 2014 Express and VS 2013 Express for web installed on my machine.

I haven't developed in many years so I need a small app that I can download and easily run, not looking to learn how to code it. Can someone point me to a project that I can download for this purpose? I'm having a hard time finding one.

Thanks,
M.

Comment: Nerd Dinner. http://nerddinner.com/

Comment: Cool, I'll look into it. Thanks!